# MySQL primary key in concurrent and cached environment

Tags: mysql, grails, caching, primary-key, scalability

I've always used auto_increment for primary keys, but in a concurrent (multi-user) system can be dangerous, especially if I have (for scalability reasons ) more grails apps running using the same database.

If I have just a minimum cache switched on on the several grails it could happen that some new BD items creation fail because each grails thinks to have the next id (but it is true only in its cached scope) and database can sometimes gives primary key violation error.

A rough solution it is not to use autoincrement integer for primary key but to use string id assigned , and to use/assign randomized string; but it does not seem to me quite elegant and may be still dangerous...

Any hint?
Thanks

Comment: Clustering the cache as well? That way it stays in sync across all your applications?

Comment: Probably I am not understanding: each grails has its own cache system. The question is: what happens when I have entity.save(flush: false)? Does grails simply make an entity insert queue waiting for mySQL saving data really or does grails have a primary id got from its cache?     This is what I do not know exactly, because I got primary key violation error from my DB and I am trying to fix that bug...